# Reading text field from recordset returns "?'s"

Tags: c++, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005, dao

I have a SQL Server 2005 Table with a TEXT type field. The record queried has the value of "Hello" in this text field. When I try to access the field from a C++ program using msado15, with the statement

```
CString CDataset::GetFieldAsString(char * FieldName)
{
    if(this->IsNull(FieldName))
        return "";
    else
        return this->pRs->Fields->Item[FieldName]->Value.bstrVal;
}
```

it returns "??????????????????"

The Database is using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, but I don't know my way around Visual C++ enough to determine if this has something to do with character sets or unicode.

Comment: You should check the type of `Value` (`Value.vt`) to make sure it is a `VT_BSTR`.  What type does your function return?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I updated the post to show the full function. It turns out that the value is VT_NULL. I'm guessing that newer SQL Drivers do not support the TEXT column type.

Comment: Phew, now would be a good time to upgrade that unsupported version of SQL Server